# How to clear MacOS Internet Sharing Wi-Fi settings?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, ethernet, internet-sharing

I've got a Nov 2023 MacBook Pro running Sonoma 14.2.1.

While initially testing Internet Sharing, I configured sharing from Ethernet to devices using Wi-Fi. In the dialog box to set up the Wi-Fi hotspot details (name, channel, security, and password) there were, I believe, around 8 channel choices to choose from. The first 4 I think were for the 2.4 GHz range, and the rest were for 5 GHz.

After attempting some other setting options, like trying to share ethernet with iPad USB and failing to get that to work, I attempted go back to using Wi-Fi, however found that the channels "pull down" no longer had any choices to choose from.

Unfortunately it seems to default to channel 11 now, which is far slower than where I had originally had it (Channel 48).

I've tried rebooting, enabling / disabling Wi-Fi, etc., but I can't get that pull down to populate. I'm hoping someone here knows of a way to nuke where these settings are stored so that the GUI presents me with the channel list again, or barring that, finding the storage area where I can hand-edit that channel value.

[image: Internet sharing configuration dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to 14.3, searching through nvram settings, all of the plist files, and sqlite files I could find and finding nothing, I resorted to booting in safe mode.
Something about that process fixed this issue.